# Unable to sort array according to containing number

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

My `NSArray` contains `NSDictionary` instances, and in the dictionaries I have orderid.
I want to make them sort in descending order. But it is not sorting.

I have tried this code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"orderid" ascending:FALSE];
[self.orderArray sortUsingDescriptors:[self.orderArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];
```

And this code :

```
 [self.orderArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderid" ascending:NO]]];
```

But it didn't worked.

Here is the log

```
orders : (
        {
        orderid = 6739;
    },
        {
        orderid = 6740;
    },
        {
        orderid = 6745;
    },
        {
        orderid = 6746;
    },
        {
        orderid = 6748;
    },
)
```

Comment: What Class is `orderid`? And what values? Show a log of the array contents before and after the sort.

Comment: The sort descriptor should work.  I'm not sure what you're doing in the second line of that first example, though -- arrayWithObject isn't an instance method.  And, to be clear, you're saying that the code executes without error, but doesn't produce a sorted array?  What is the final result?

Comment: @HotLicks the log display is final result.

Comment: Use sortedArrayUsingDescriptors instead, and see if it returns (as a result you'd assign to a new variable) a new sorted array, to see if it's doing anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am  agree with the @HotLicks this code must work. Are you sure between the sort code and log there is no code. If there is than please add it.

Only problem i see is that You have added your array name instead of NSArray in `[self.orderArray sortUsingDescriptors:[self.orderArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];` this line.

Do it like this :

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"orderid" ascending:FALSE];
 [self.orderArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]]; //Change in this line
 [sortDescriptor release];

 NSLog(@"self.orderArray : %@",self.orderArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderid.intValue" ascending:NO ];
 [self.orderArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array using your "custom" comparator.

```
NSMutableArray *nds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:nodes];
//
[nds sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Node *f1,Node *f2){
    if (f1.nodeType == FOLDER && f2.nodeType == FILE) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (f1.nodeType == FILE && f2.nodeType == FOLDER) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (f1.nodeType == f2.nodeType) {
        return [f1.displayName localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:f2.displayName];
    }
    //
    return [f1.displayName compare:f2.displayName];
}];
```

This method will traverse the array, taking two objects from the array and comparing them.
The advantage is that the objects can be of any type (class) and you decide the order between the two.
In the above example I want to order:
- folders before files
- folders and files in alphabetical order